# Column value becomes NULL after inserting with BindingSource

Tags: c#, dataset, bindingsource

I am using DataSet, DataAdapter and BindingSource in my c# application.
below is code samle.

```
bindsrcStudents.AddNew();
DataRow currRow = (bindsrcStudents.Current as DataRowView).Row;
currRow["StudentNo"] = txtStudentNo.Text;
currRow["Name"] = txtName.Text;
currRow["Surname"] = txtSurname.Text;
currRow["BirthDate"] = dateBirth.Value.ToShortDateString();
currRow["PhotoPath"] = pictureBox.ImageLocation;
currRow["Gender"] = comboGender.SelectedIndex;
bindsrcStudents.EndEdit();
adapterStudent.Update(dsMain,"Students");
```

But after `bindsrcStudents.EndEdit()` line `bindsrcStudents.EndEdit()` converts
to NULL. I don't know why. There is not any problem with other columns, but only with
**PhotoPath** column.

What is the problem?

Comment: Where you called `PictureBox.Load(PicturePath)` method? Can you apply breakpoint on the line and check the value?

Comment: An image loads into the pictureBox. I can see an image. And when I debug the code, there is a value in currRow["PhotoPath"]. But after bindsrcStudents.EndEdit() it becomes NULL.